# how to result two values inside one variable in cfscript/cfml

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

hi I am converting a sql statement where I have a where clause and a in operator in it where I am trying to get the two id numbers to show the record on screen. But for some reason I only get the first id to print on the screen so. Here is a snippet to my code.

`if (item.employeeId == '878789' && '987348'))`

and my sql statement where clause looks like this.

`where employee_id in ('878789', '987348')`

Comment: Hopefully you are using cfqueryparam in the real code.. It also has a list attribute that comes in handy.

Comment: no idea about coldfusion, but `item.employeeId == '878789' && '987348'` looks strange to me. -- its `A == B AND  C`, isnt it? Shouldnt it be  something like `if (item.employeeId == '878789' ||  item.employeeId == '987348'))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem with if statement, try

```
if (item.employeeId == '878789' || item.employeeId == '987348'))
```

Answer (score 5):

2 of the best ways to do this is to use [`ListFind`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfind.html) or [`ArrayFind`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayfind.html). If you need to check more than one values I would go for this over multiple `OR` in `if` statement.

```
if (ListFind('878789,987348', item.employeeId))
```

OR

```
if (ArrayFind([878789,987348], item.employeeId))
```

Also it would be beneficial for you to save the list/array in a variable if you are dynamically creating the ids.

Comment: Array processing is likely faster than List/string processing.

Comment: Yes, the find method is more readable when searching for multiple values.

Comment: @JamesAMohler True, that is quite likely that Array is fastest way. But when you have a list and it might be more reasonable to do the listfind rather than converting list to array.